# Dart : Make reusable try catch block for error handling

Tags: dart

I have simple function login request to server, in this function i have some error handling .

#### Example Source Code

```
try {
      final response = await http.post(
        '${appConfig.baseApiUrl}/${appConfig.userController}/loginUser',
        headers: appConfig.headersApi,
        body: {
          "username": username,
          "password": password,
        },
      );
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List userList = responseJson['data'];
        List<UserModel> result = userList.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
        return result;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson['message']);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.error(ConstText.NO_CONNECTION);
    } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
      return Future.error(ConstText.TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION);
    } on FormatException catch (_) {
      return Future.error(ConstText.FORMAT_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

In above source code, I have 4 Handling error like **SocketException,TimeoutException,FormatException and UnknownException**. This function work fine, but if i create another function for request server i should repeat the error handling again.
My question is , it's possible to make error handling reusable ? I want something like this.

#### Example Reusable Try Catch

```
requestServer(yourRequestServer) async{
  try{
    return yourRequestServer;
  }on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.error(ConstText.NO_CONNECTION);
    } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
      return Future.error(ConstText.TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION);
    } on FormatException catch (_) {
      return Future.error(ConstText.FORMAT_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

#### How To Use it

```
Future<String> testLogin(String username,String password)async{
requestServer({
final response = await http.post(
        '${appConfig.baseApiUrl}/${appConfig.userController}/loginUser',
        headers: appConfig.headersApi,
        body: {
          "username": username,
          "password": password,
        },
      );
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List userList = responseJson['data'];
        List<UserModel> result = userList.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
        return result;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson['message']);
      }
});
}
```

Or if you have another suggestion , i really appreciate that. 
Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reusing code is always a matter of figuring out what to keep an what to abstract away.
In your case, you want to reuse the `catch` clauses.
The thing you are abstracting over is the body of the `try` clause, which appears to contain some asynchronous code. 
Since you are abstracting over code, you'll need to pass in a *function*. That's the only way to make code into an argument value.

So you'll need something like:

```dart
Future<T> requestServer(FutureOr<T> computation()) {
  try {
    return await computation();
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    throw ConstText.NO_CONNECTION;
  } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
    throw ConstText.TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION;
  } on FormatException catch (_) {
    throw ConstText.FORMAT_EXCEPTION;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e.toString();
  }
}
```

You can then use it as:

```dart
var result = await requestServer(() {
   final response = await http.post(...
   ...
     return result;
   ...
});
```

I changed the `return Future.error(someString);` to `throw someString` because *it's the same thing*, and the latter is much more readable. You are throwing *strings* here, not exception or error objects. That's a bold move, but as long as you are the one to catch them again, it's reasonable. It's not a good API for other people to have to catch.

Comment: After little improve your code, like create generic class for more reusable, it's working fine. Thank's ! https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB0pf.png

Comment: @Irn But can i ask you one question ? I implement this function in futurebuilder, but futurebuilder can't catch the error insted of this make app crash.

Comment: I don't know much about `FutureBuilder`, but I'm guessing it needs the future to *not* contain an error. So, you have to handle the error somehow, not just throw it again. Maybe wrap the result in a [`Result`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/Result-class.html) which can contain either a value or error, but is itself just a value.